# Phalcon 4 validation multipart/form-data multiple

Tags: php, forms, upload, phalcon

Is it possible to configure the file validator of Phalcon4, where it can validate multiple uploaded files?

I cannot find any documentation about multiple files upload, just file upload with different form fields: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/api/phalcon_validation#validation-validator-file

I can validate files which are uploaded one by one, but I need the form to handle multiple uploaded files at once.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="formFile" name="media[]" multiple>
```

**Controller**

```
$validation = new FileUploadValidation();
$validation->validate($_FILES);
```

**FileUploadValidation.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Validator;

use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\File as FileValidator;

class FileUploadValidation extends Validation
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->add(
            ['media'],
            new FileValidator(
                [
                    "maxSize"              => "2M",
                    "messageSize"          => ":field exceeds the max file size (:size)",
                    "allowedTypes"         => [
                        "image/jpeg",
                        "image/png",
                    ],
                    "messageType"          => "Allowed file types are :types",
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each file and validate it:

```
$validation = new FileUploadValidation();
   
foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file) { 
    $messages[] = $validation->validate($file);
}

if (count($messages)) {
  ...
}
```

Also, in your `add` definition you do not need to place an array, just a string (replace `['media']` with `'media'`:

```
$this->add(
        'media',
        new FileValidator([...]}
);
```